# Return jQuery AJAX output as return if a function

Tags: jquery, javascript

I called a web serivce via jQuery AJAX. web service returned 'True' as output.
I want to return as return of a function. but it returns undefined.

Where is the source of problem ?
Function IsAuthenticated returns undefined however response.d contains 'True' value (its string).

```
   function IsAuthenticated() {
        //Todo Check If user logined or not from server
       return CallWebService("Server/WebServices/Server.asmx/IsUserLogined", '{}');
    }
    function CallWebService(WebServicePath, parameters) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: WebServicePath,
            data: parameters,
            async: false,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                if (response.d == 'True') {

                    return true;
                }
                else
                { return false; }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {

                alert("error");

            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call) and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are using async:false option to make the ajax calls synchronous.

However the success function is still a callback and returning true from the success handler will not return the value as a result of the ajax function call.

You need to capture the output into a local variable and return it.

Try this:

```
function CallWebService(WebServicePath, parameters) {
    var retValue = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: WebServicePath,
            data: parameters,
            async: false,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
                if (response.d == 'True') {
                      retValue = true;
                }
                else
                {  retValue =  false; }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return retValue;
}
```

Comment: Though I wouldn't advise making ajax calls syncronous, yes you got it right to make the call synchrous, just change the code to recieve the value of the call in success handler and assign it to a local variable that is returned after the ajax method statement